# error Error [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled. at Mongoose.model

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mongoose, next.js

I created a user Authentication System with Next.js but what happened once I signup then when i went to login then this error occurred and when I stop runnning application (ctrl+c) and then again run then it works fine

## The error

```
- error Error [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
    at Mongoose.model (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:563:13)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/models/userModel.js:45:128)
    at (rsc)/./src/models/userModel.js (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\app\api\users\login\route.js:1549:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/users/login/route.js:6:75)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/api/users/login/route.js (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\app\api\users\login\route.js:1527:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Flogin%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Flogin%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Flogin%2Froute.js&appDir=E%3A%5CTUTORIALS-web%5CPROJECT%5Cfull%20Stack%20Projects%5CUserAuthentication_Next.js%5Cuser-authentication%5Csrc%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=E%3A%5CTUTORIALS-web%5CPROJECT%5Cfull%20Stack%20Projects%5CUserAuthentication_Next.js%5Cuser-authentication&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D!:16:181)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-app-loader.js?name=app%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Flogin%2Froute&page=%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Flogin%2Froute&appPaths=&pagePath=private-next-app-dir%2Fapi%2Fusers%2Flogin%2Froute.js&appDir=E%3A%5CTUTORIALS-web%5CPROJECT%5Cfull%20Stack%20Projects%5CUserAuthentication_Next.js%5Cuser-authentication%5Csrc%5Capp&pageExtensions=tsx&pageExtensions=ts&pageExtensions=jsx&pageExtensions=js&rootDir=E%3A%5CTUTORIALS-web%5CPROJECT%5Cfull%20Stack%20Projects%5CUserAuthentication_Next.js%5Cuser-authentication&isDev=true&tsconfigPath=tsconfig.json&basePath=&assetPrefix=&nextConfigOutput=&preferredRegion=&middlewareConfig=e30%3D! (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\app\api\users\login\route.js:99:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_exec__ (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\app\api\users\login\route.js:1603:39)
    at E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\app\api\users\login\route.js:1604:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\.next\server\app\api\users\login\route.js:1607:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at requirePage (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\node_modules\next\dist\server\require.js:112:75)
    at E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:80:84
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async loadComponentsImpl (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\node_modules\next\dist\server\load-components.js:80:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (E:\TUTORIALS-web\PROJECT\full Stack Projects\UserAuthentication_Next.js\user-authentication\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:439:36) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

## MY SIGNUP route.js

```
import { connect } from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig.js";
import User from "@/models/userModel.js";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";

connect();

export const POST = async (NextRequest) => {
  try {
    const reqBody = await NextRequest.json();
    const { username, email, password } = reqBody;
    console.log(reqBody);

    //check if user already exist
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "User already exists" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }
    // hash password
    const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      username,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    console.log(savedUser);

    return NextResponse.json({
        message: "User is created Successfully",
        success: true,
        savedUser
    });

    

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in signup=>", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
};
```

## Login route.js

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';


export function middleware(request) {
   const path = request.nextUrl.pathname;
   const isPublicPath = path === '/login' || path == '/signup';

   const token = request.cookies.get('token')?.value || ''

   if(isPublicPath && token){
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/profile', request.nextUrl));
   }

   if (!isPublicPath && !token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.nextUrl));
   }

}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/', '/profile', '/login', '/signup'],
}
```

## dbconfig.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export async function connect () {
    try {
        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
        const connection = mongoose.connection;

        connection.on('connected', () => {
            console.log("Database connected");
        })

        connection.on('error', (err) =>{
            console.log('Error while connecting database', err);
            process.exit();
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error in connecting database =>",error);
    }
}
```

I want when to signup then restart the server I am able to log in or when I logout then without restarting the server I am again able to login but I have to restart it

according to me- my mongoose modal is recompilig again and again is there is any way in next.js that only one time my mongoose modal are compile

Comment: The error is clearly related to your model. So please add your model/schema related code with your question.